# How can I benchmark performance with pagespeed-insights as different locations / devices are getting quite varied results?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I am working to improve speed performance and I am using PageSpeed Insights and web.dev.

I'd like to record the current state so I can benchmark and track improvements. When using PageSpeed Insights, I understand that a little variance when running the test is expected, but working with a remote team (USA, Canada, England, etc...) we have seen scores from 46 to 73 which is quite a big range.

How can I get ~consistent results to accurately track any improvements made?

Thanks